# WriteRegStr HKLM: Cross Windows Platform Solution

Tags: installation, 64-bit, nsis

On Windows 7/64 Bit Computers the NSIS function `WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" "blah" "blah"` doesn't work.

From my understanding the only way to get it to work is to do this: `WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" "blah" "blah"`

**Am I correct that this is the only way to write to the Local Machine Registry on Windows 7/64 Bit Computers?**

*Is there a cross platform way/function that can write to the Local Machine Registry?*

Is my only option something like this...

```
!macro WriteRegStrLocalMachine path regName regValue

    WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\${path}" "${regName}" "${regValue}"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\${path}" "${regName}" "${regValue}"
!macroend

!macro ReadRegStrLocalMachine path regName regValue

    ReadRegStr $1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\${path}" "${regName}"
    ReadRegStr $2 HKLM "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\${path}" "${regName}"

    # TODO: Check if $1 or $2 contain data 
!macroend
```

Comment: WOW6432Node is for 32 bits applications installed on 64-bit OS. You should read/write the right path depending on whether  the installed application is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: @FranciscoR I unsure what you mean but if you call the function WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" "blah" "blah" on a 64bit computer you will see that the registry is never written. I dont think it has anything to do with what I am installing, it just wont appear in the registry regardless

Comment: You have to run your installer as an administrative user in order to be able to write to HKLM (or HKCU) in Vista or higher (or on XP as well if the current user is not a power user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct that this is the only way to write to the Local Machine Registry on Windows 7/64 Bit Computers?

Wrong: with NSIS (that is a 32b application until a next release - the current being 2.46), you can choose to access either the 64b or the 32b by using [`SetRegView`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.7.6)